# Recieving "instance of __PHP_Incomplete_Class given" when storing the Facebook session in the PHP $_SESSION array

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am attempting to implement the server side PHP facebook authentication code, to go with my front end Javascript Facebook authentication code.

For this, I am grabbing the current facebook session, storing it into the PGP $_SESSION array, and then using it to make a call to get the user's username.

On the 2nd time into the side, i check to see if we have the stored facebook session in the PHP $_SESSION array, and if so, I use that again to make the call to get the user name.  This is where i recieve the "instance of __PHP_Incomplete_Class given" error message, when trying to use the stored session.

The reason i want to store the facebook session between page refreshes is that whenever i call $session = $helper->getSession(); a second time after the user logs in, i receive a message "this authorization code has already been used".  I read somewhere that you need to store the facebook session, instead of calling for a new one each refresh, as the facebook token was already consumed in getting you the first session object.

Can anyone help me figure out how to store the facebook session in the PHP $_SESSION array correctly, and be able to pull it back out, and use it to make calls to facebook?

I am using the latest facebook JS sdk and the latest facebook PHP sdk.

CODE:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/GraphUser.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
require_once ('facebookphpsdkv4/src/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');

useFacebookGraphObject;
useFacebookGraphUser;
useFacebookGraphSessionInfo;
useFacebookEntitiesAccessToken;
useFacebookFacebookSession;
useFacebookEntitiesSignedRequest;
useFacebookFacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper;
useFacebookFacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper;
useFacebookHttpClientsFacebookHttpable;
useFacebookHttpClientsFacebookCurl;
useFacebookHttpClientsFacebookCurlHttpClient;
useFacebookFacebookResponse;
useFacebookFacebookRequest;
useFacebookFacebookSDKException;
useFacebookFacebookRequestException;
useFacebookFacebookAuthorizationException;
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('AppID', 'AppSecret');

if (isset($_SESSION['session']))
    {
    echo 'session set';
    $session = $_SESSION['session'];
    }
  else
    {
    $helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();
    try
        {
        $session = $helper->getSession();
        $_SESSION['session'] = $session;
        }

    catch(FacebookRequestException $e)
        {
        echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
        echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    catch(Exception $e)
        {
        echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
        echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

if ($session)
    {
    try
        {
        $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile->getName();
        }

    catch(FacebookRequestException $e)
        {
        echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
        echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: You need to make sure that the appropriate classes have been included before your session_start

Comment: @MarkBaker Are you sure that would work? That seems strange, but i guess if PHP does not know about the structure of the session ahead of time, it would not know how to parse or deserialize it? I will try.

Comment: That's precisely what the problem is.... and using an autoloader doesn't work with unserializing objects from session

Comment: It seems like that worked @MarkBaker. Thanks for the pin point accuracy on the answer and the quick response.  If you want, please make a answer, and i will accept it as correct, as you were the first one to suggest the correct fix.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an __PHP_Incomplete_Class error because you get your sessions (with `session_start()` call) before including you class files.

There are objects of a type unknown by PHP (as your requires are *after* your `session_start()`) in your session variables, so PHP doesn't know how to "rebuild" theses objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It seems like this is the correct course of action.  There was a comment on the question that answered it first though, so i am giving them a chance to make a answer. if they do not, i will select your answer as the correct solution.  Thanks again